# Segger J-Link (or i-jet) with Renesas R-Car H3 and IAR

Tags: arm, iar, segger-jlink

Does anyone know how to use a Segger JLink or IAR I-Jet with a Renesas R-Car H3 Cortex-R7 core?

I can't find anything on the Segger or IAR website.

Comment: This may well be because the  Cortex-R7 is not supported, even though the R4, R5 and R8 are. I would suggest to ask you question directly on the [JLink forum](https://forum.segger.com/index.php/Board/3-J-Link-Flasher-related/) : people at Segger are usually very responsive.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the problem by building with IAR and debugging with ARM Developer Studio and a DStream debugger.